# Stateless Programming with Relational Database

Tags: javascript, stateless

I am try to code as stateless as possible. However, I got stuck when it comes to interaction with relational database.

```
var fetchDataFromTable = function(tableName) 
{  
 //dummy result from using mysql library
 sqlQuery = "Select * from " + tableName;
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) 
 {
   con.query(sqlQuery, function(err,body)
    {
   resolve(body)
    })
 })
}

var getOrderName = function(checkOrderID,fetchDataFromTable)
{
   //Here, I have to hard-code the table name.
   fetchFromTable("OrderTable").then(function(result)
    {

      //dummy function. Can use SQL query instead of looping.
       result.forEach(function(index){
         if (result[index].orderID == checkOrderID)
            return result[index].orderName;
       })
    })
}

orderName = getOrderName("A123",fetchDataFromTable);
```

The sample code above shows an example of relying the result from the database to make certain decisions. In this case, i am using ".orderID".

My question is, is this consider as stateless? If not, how can I make it more "stateless"?

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by stateless.

By definition a database is stateful (the whole point of it is to store stuff) so technically what you are doing is not stateless.

However, when people refer to a stateless web app, they generally mean "free of session state," not free of state entirely.

Your code example does not appear to use any session state, so it may be fair to call this a stateless solution.